# EJS Template for webpack plugin 'html-webpack-plugin'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I want to load a custom template for the plugin 'html-webpack-plugin'.

I have this [index.ejs](https://github.com/sarovin/React-Starter/blob/test/app/assets/index.ejs)
and this [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/sarovin/React-Starter/blob/test/webpack.config.js)

But I have this error when build:

> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
>   Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/saro/Projects/react-starter/app/assets/index.ejs: Unexpected token (1:1)

`1 | <!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: aren't you missing the ejs loader ? or at least an html loader ?

Comment: @topheman how do i configre my webpack with ejs loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, install the loader:

```
npm install ejs-loader --save-dev
```

then update your webpack.config.js (add `ejs!`):

```
  plugins: [
    new HtmlwebpackPlugin({
      title: 'React Starter Kit',
      hash: true,
      inject: false,
      appMountId: 'app',
      template: 'ejs!app/assets/index.ejs'
    })
  ]
```

Comment: not solve : ERROR in ./~/ejs-loader!./app/assets/index.ejs
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: ~/react-starter/app/assets/index.ejs: Unexpected token (1:1)

Comment: Sorry, i have lost this : { test: /\.ejs$/, loader: "ejs-loader?variable=data" }

Comment: in my case, it works but with few modifications which I finally able to find after some googling doodling. I have used     template: '!!ejs-loader!./views/index.ejs'